# Composition of Measurable and Discontinuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider a locally-bounded function $f: W \rightarrow X$, $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.

Assume that $f$ is Borel measurable

(for every open $O \in \Sigma_X$ ($\sigma$-algebra of $X$) we have $f^{-1}(O) \in \Sigma_W$ ($\sigma$-algebra of $W$))

Consider a locally-bounded discontinuous function $g: X \rightarrow Y$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$.

1. Say if $\ g \circ f: W \rightarrow Y$ is measurable as well.
2. If not: counterexample?
3. If not: under which conditions is $g \circ f$ measurable?

Comment: It's obvious from the definition of measurability that if two functions are measurable then their composition is measurable. But at a wild guess I'd say $g$ is not necessarily measurable.

Comment: That's why I was first asking 1. :-)

Seems to me that if we define $\bar{g}(w,x) := g(x)$, then for all $x \in X$, we have $w \mapsto \bar{g}(x,w)$ measurable (because constant).

Comment: ...Why would you do that? What sort of thing is $w$? I don't even know what $w$ you are talking about in your question 1.

Comment: When I say "measurable", we mean functions from $W$ to $\mathbb{R}^{something}$. I'll adjust question 1. accordingly (to avoid confusion, I'll make it question 2.). So I don't see what do you mean by $g$ not measurable, because its domain is not ($\subseteq$) $W$.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but that's not the normal definition of measurable function. Usually, we define "measurable" to mean "the pre-images of measurable sets are measurable" (i.e. your definition, but using the appropriate Borel algebra for the domain and range of the function you are considering). Is it possible that you've misunderstood the definition you've been given?

Comment: (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function))

Comment: (also, it's possible that $g \circ f$ is measurable even if $g$ isn't; I didn't do much measure theory so I'm not too precise on the details)

Comment: Could be. I mean the definition of measurability provided in the question. To avoid confusion, let's delete the question on measurability of $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=m=p=1$. Take $f:R \mapsto (0,1)$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$, which is locally bounded, continuous and measurable. Let $V$ be the [vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) which is not measurable in $B(\mathcal{R})$. Let $g: (0,1) \mapsto \{0,1\}$,

$$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
        1 & \mbox{$x \in V$};\\
        0 & \mbox{$x \notin V$}.\end{array} \right. $$

$g \circ f$ is not measurable. If $g$ is continuous, $g \circ f$ is measurable. In general, if $g$ is measurable, $g \circ f$ is measurable.